# No keyboard output on terminal after running a script using read and whiptail

Tags: bash, background-process, read, dialog, whiptail

I've written a bash function that accepts a command as an argument, runs it in the background, and allows the user to kill the command by pressing any key. This part works fine.

However, when I pipe it to a `whiptail` dialog gauge, the whiptail runs as expected, but after it returns, the terminal will no longer display keypresses. I can still run commands, I just don't see what I'm typing printed to the screen. The output is also formatted weirdly, where stdout appears after `$`.

I'm pretty sure the `read` command is responsible for this behavior, but I don't understand why. Can anyone offer any insight?

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
function killOnKeypress() {
    local runcommand="${1}"
    local args=(${@:2})

    # Run the command in the background
    "${runcommand}" ${args[@]} &

    # Get the process id of $runcommand
    local pid=$!

    # Monitor $runcommand and listen for keypress in foreground
    while kill -0 "${pid}" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
        # If key pressed, kill $runcommand and return with code 1
        read -sr -n 1 -t 1 && kill "${pid}" && return 1
    done

    # Set $? to return code of $runcommand
    wait $pid

    # Return $runcommand's exit code
    return $?
}

function count100() {
    for ((i = 0; i < 100; i++)); do
        echo $i
        sleep .02
    done
}

killOnKeypress "count100" | whiptail \
    --gauge "Counting to 100" \
    16 56 \
    0
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this doesn't answer OP question, it can be useful for someone else landed here, looking for the fix/workaround.

As NickD in his comment pointed out, whiptail sets -echo (in my environment not just  echo).

To fix your script you can put

```
stty echo
```

at the end of it.

What your script (whiptail) changes you can see with 'stty -a' before and after your script is run.
Of course you can save the outputs to files and make it easier to spot the differences:

```
stty -a > good_terminal
```

run your script - your terminal is messed, reset it with 'reset' or 'tset' or 'stty sane' and run again 'stty' command, and diff after it:

```
stty -a > bad_terminal
diff good_terminal bad_terminal
```

Comment: Thank you, this completely answers my question! I was not aware of `stty`, so I didn't know how to check to see what had changed or how to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that `whiptail` leaves the terminal in a weird state. Try `stty sane` as the command  (you'll have to type it blind, so be careful). If that fixes the terminal, then that's probably the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `stty`. I forgot to mention `reset` also works, I just wish I knew what was wrong in the first place!

Comment: As I said, apparently `whiptail` sets `-echo` and does not reset it on exit (at least in some cases). Try eliminating `whiptail` from the pipeline: does the resulting script leave the terminal in a funny state? In my experiment, it does not: the terminal works properly  afterwards. Add a `stty sane` at the end of your script: again the terminal works properly afterwards. That is enough to convince me that `whiptail` has a bug.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see any comment about `whiptail` setting `-echo`, did u delete it? Per the answer below, this seems to be exactly what I wanted to know.